# google-vr - 360 images in iframe not appearing - just black boxes

Tags: html, iframe, google-vr

I am having an issue with the Google vrview - my images are not appearing in the iframe - it is just a black box (see image). The links are definitely pointing to the right directory as if i navigate to it in my browser, the 360 image is displayed. Also, I am not getting the 'unable to load texture' message - the iframe is just black.

Anyone have any ideas on this?

[iframes as they are appearing on my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dprC.png)

Answer (score 0):

There could be some incompatibilities with your browser.

Did you check "Known issues on the Web" [here](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web) and [this](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview#web)?

Also, make sure your source image follows [these specifications](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview#image_specifications).